# Angular2 AngularFire2 How to get users from authentication section ? (Facebook Login)

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I've successfully integrated Firebase login in my app, but now I have an issue when I try to get a records.

Those users which are created using email and password are visible in my users table in database. But those who logged in with a facebook are only visible in Authentication section in Firebase console. How can I get all users from Authentication section in my Angular 2 application ? Or find a specific user from authentication section with Id ?

PS:

Example of how I get a records:

```
this.friendList = this.af.database.list('/friend-list', {

  query: {
    limitToLast: 10
  }

});

this.friendList.subscribe(messages => {

    console.log('firendlist:');
    console.log(messages);
});
```

Comment: If Firebase Authentication users are added to the Firebase Database, your app contains code to add them there. You will need to expand this code to also add the email+password users to the database when they sign in.

Comment: I have names of users who logged in using just email and password, but such credentials like uid and name from Facebook login and Google login are not shown in database they only shown in authentication panel in Firebase console on the website. How can I get those details?

Comment: That's the same information you've already put in your original question. As I said in my first comment: you must have code in your app that writes the user info to the database. You'll need to fix/expand that code to also handle Facebook and Google sign-ins.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway. I thought there is other way to do it :)